# Перенести блок с поиском под шапку css

Tags: css, ucoz

На сайте https://knigomania.org/ имеется адаптивный дизайн, но при нем блок с поиском уходит почти в самый низ страницы, на что очень жалуются пользователи. Подскажите, можно как-то перенести его в самый верх страницы под шапку?
Если это важно, то сайт сделан в системе ucoz.

Comment: Через код, как обычно.

Comment: @Duoxx ну Вы хотя бы подсказали в сторону чего смотреть)

Comment: Тут никакой стороны не нужно